# How can I bypass Google login in Selenium automation

Tags: java, authentication, selenium-webdriver, oauth-2.0, automated-tests

I have a website where I only can log in by using Google API "Sign in with Google". It looks like Google blocks the UI automation process. I need automationm but can not bypass the login process. I need a solution for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you could, Google would be insecure and broken for *everybody*.

You need to design your site in such a way that, during tests, you bypass the login process. There are lots of ways of doing this, like having an endpoint available in your test environment that creates the client/server state necessary to establish a session without going through Google first.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could log in to the site on your own, dump the cookies you got into a file and use it for your Selenium script and hope that the site just accepts the session cookie and won't kill it or anything. Then you could bypass the need to log in using Google.

But google doesn't really want you to automatically log in so you probably won't find a good way to bypass their checks.